# Hide Column In Grid

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, gridview

This is my html mark-up and adding the visibility to false in the div tag hides the actual data itself, but just leaves a blank column.  I tried to access the div tag (yes I added the `runat="server"` tag to the html) and attempted to access it like so `hideme.Visible = true;` which threw a compile error of

> Does not exist in the current context.

What should I alter/modify to ensure that this column is completely hidden from my grid?

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowFooter="true"
        onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound"  onrowcreated="GridView1_RowCreated">
    <Columns>
      <asp:BoundField DataField="abcd" HeaderText="abcd" />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="def" HeaderText="def" />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="hij" HeaderText="hij" />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="xyz" HeaderText="xyz" />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="eee" HeaderText="eee" />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="era" HeaderText="era" />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="nai" HeaderText="nai" />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="fac" HeaderText="fac" />
      <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div runat="server" style="visibility:hidden" id="hideme">
                    <asp:Label ID="lbllunch" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("hij") %>' />
                    <asp:Label ID="lbllunchoverage" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("xyz") %>' />
                    <asp:Label ID="lbleee" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("eee") %>' />
                    <asp:Label ID="lblera" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("era") %>' />
                    <asp:Label ID="lblnai" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("nai") %>' />
                    <asp:Label ID="lblfac" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("fac") %>' />
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**EDIT**
I added the `.Visible` command to my page load event (where I always hide anything on my page) like so:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    hideme.Visible = false;
    /More here
}
```

Comment: where do you put hideme.Visible = true; code? Can you post it?

Comment: What you you really should learn is the difference in CSS between `visibility:hidden` which hides the content but **keeps the space** for it and `display:none` which hides the element entirely. Note that setting `visible=false` on the server will result in the html element not even being rendered to the page so you will lose any clientside javascript interaction with the object. You would then have to post back to the server to display the item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `hideme` is inside the GridView TemplateField, you can't access it in `Page_Load` method, however you can access it in `GridView1_RowDataBound` method as below

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        // find the hideme div
        HtmlGenericControl div = (HtmlGenericControl)e.Row.FindControl("hideme");

        // set the visible property
        div.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the column in DataBound event of gridview.

```
protected void GridView_DataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{    
    GridView.Columns[8].Visible = false;       

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide  template field column why you are adding it to markup. Yes if you keep `style="visibility:hidden"` it will show blank column only because item template still exists as column.

My suggestion for you is if dont need column dnt add markup.